# KSOAP Complex response parsing

Tags: parsing, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I am currently using KSOAP2 for my project which is linked to a SOAP WebService. So far I have managed to get a result but now i had like to parse that result into a POJO. I have read that with using `addMapping(namespace,node,class)`
I could get my result into that Object but I don't know where is the problem in my code.
So my question would be: How to parse KSOAP response into my custom Object?

the wsdl : http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?wsdl

My XML Response

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <GetGeoIPResponse xmlns="http://www.webservicex.net/">
         <GetGeoIPResult>
            <ReturnCode>1</ReturnCode>
            <IP>127.0.0.1</IP>
            <ReturnCodeDetails>Success</ReturnCodeDetails>
            <CountryName>Reserved</CountryName>
            <CountryCode>ZZZ</CountryCode>
         </GetGeoIPResult>
      </GetGeoIPResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

MainActivity.java

```
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://www.webservicex.net/GetGeoIP";
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "GetGeoIP";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://www.webservicex.net/";
private static final String URL = "http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?wsdl";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

addProperty("IPAddress","127.0.0.1");


SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
soapEnvelope.dotNet= true;

soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
soapEnvelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE,"getGeoIPResponse", new GetGeoIPResponse().getClass());
soapEnvelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE,"getGeoIPResult", new GetGeoIPResult().getClass());

soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
transport.debug = true;


try {
     transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
} catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
} catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}

 SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;


 Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + resultString);
 } catch (Exception ex) {
     Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + ex.getMessage());
 }
```

GetGeoResponse.java

```
public class GetGeoIPResponse implements KvmSerializable{

    GetGeoIPResult getGeoIPResult = new GetGeoIPResult();

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int index) {
        if( index == 0 ){
            return this.getGeoIPResult;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        if( index == 0){
            this.getGeoIPResult =(GetGeoIPResult) value;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {

        if(index == 0){
            info.name = "GetGeoIPResult";
            info.type = GetGeoIPResult.class;
        }
    }
}
```

GetGeoIPResult.java

```
public class GetGeoIPResult implements KvmSerializable {

    private Integer returnCode;
    private String IP;
    private String returnCodeDetails;
    private String countryName;
    private String countryCode;

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int index) {
        switch (index){
            case 0: return returnCode;
            case 1: return IP;
            case 2: return returnCodeDetails;
            case 3: return countryName;
            case 4: return countryCode;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 5;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        switch (index){
            case 0:
                returnCode = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
                break;
            case 1:
                IP = value.toString();
                break;
            case 2:
                returnCodeDetails = value.toString();
                break;
            case 3:
                countryName = value.toString();
                break;
            case 4:
                countryCode = value.toString();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch (index){
            case 0:
                info.name = "ReturnCode";
                info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                break;
            case 1:
                info.name = "IP";
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            case 2:
                info.name = "ReturnCodeDetails";
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            case 3:
                info.name = "CountryName";
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            case 4:
                info.name = "CountryCode";
                info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out myself here are the files:

Request

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

            request.addProperty("IPAddress","127.0.0.1");

            SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            soapEnvelope.dotNet= true;

            soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

            soapEnvelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE,"GetGeoIPResponse", GetGeoIPResponse.class);
            soapEnvelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE,"GetGeoIPResult", GetGeoIPResult.class);

            soapEnvelope.implicitTypes = true;
            HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            transport.debug = true;
            transport.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);

            GetGeoIPResponse resultString = (GetGeoIPResponse) soapEnvelope.bodyIn;
```

GetGeoIPResult.java

```
    public class GetGeoIPResult implements KvmSerializable {

        private Integer returnCode;
        private String IP;
        private String returnCodeDetails;
        private String countryName;
        private String countryCode;

        @Override
        public Object getProperty(int index) {
            switch (index){
                case 0: return returnCode;
                case 1: return IP;
                case 2: return returnCodeDetails;
                case 3: return countryName;
                case 4: return countryCode;
                default: return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getPropertyCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
            switch (index){
                case 0:
                    returnCode = Integer.parseInt(value.toString());
                    break;
                case 1:
                    IP = value.toString();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    returnCodeDetails = value.toString();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    countryName = value.toString();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    countryCode = value.toString();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
            switch (index){
                case 0:
                    info.name = "ReturnCode";
                    info.type = PropertyInfo.INTEGER_CLASS;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    info.name = "IP";
                    info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    info.name = "ReturnCodeDetails";
                    info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    info.name = "CountryName";
                    info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    info.name = "CountryCode";
                    info.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }

        }
    }
```

GetGeoIPResponse.java

```
public class GetGeoIPResponse implements KvmSerializable {

    private GetGeoIPResult getGeoIPResult;

    @Override
    public Object getProperty(int index) {
        switch (index){
            case 0:
                return getGeoIPResult;
            default: return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getPropertyCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void setProperty(int index, Object value) {
        switch (index){
            case 0:
                getGeoIPResult = (GetGeoIPResult) value;
                break;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void getPropertyInfo(int index, Hashtable properties, PropertyInfo info) {
        switch (index){
            case 0:
                info.name = "GetGeoIPResult";
                info.type = GetGeoIPResult.class;
                break;
        }

    }
}
```